# put in hashmap using two lists and database

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, many-to-many

I have two classes, User and Customer, using hibernate, I have mapped these tables, now I want to retrieve the data from the database, where I can put the values in hashmap such that for each user, if a particular customer exists in the mapping table, then the key of map is set as the customer name, and value to true or false, depending upon the mapping table.

I have retrieved both the lists:

```
static List<User> listUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
static List<Customer> listCustomers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
List<UserTO> list = new ArrayList<UserTO>();

public static List<Customer> getListOfCustomers() {
    HibernateUtil.openSession();
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        listCustomers = session.createQuery("from Customer").list();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return listCustomers;
}
(similarly list of users)
```

in UserTO class, I have:

```
public class UserTO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String userId;
private Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
(getter and setter)
```

I tried doing this:

```
public static void execute() {
    getListOfUsers();
    getListOfCustomers();
    for (User user : listUsers) {
        UserTO u = new UserTO();
        Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Customer customer : listCustomers) {
            if (customer.getCompanyName() == user.getCustomers(customer)) {
                map.put(customer.getCompanyName(), true);
            } else {
                map.put(customer.getCompanyName(), false);
            }
        }
        user.getUserId();
        u.setUserId(user.getUserId());
        u.setMap(map);
        listUsers.add(user);
    }
}
```

which gives me **Concurrent Modification Exception**
I don't know where I am doing wrong, and what should I do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are adding user to listUsers when you are iterating over this listuser. This results in the given exception.

Use list.add(u);

Answer (score 1):

Reason for [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) is you are trying to add to the list at the same time when you are iterating like:

```
for (User user : listUsers) {
....
    listUsers.add(user);
```

One way to solve this would be to create a temporary list and keep adding to that list and after your for loop, use `addAll` method on `listUsers` to add all your users that you added in the loop.

Note: Inorder to select the data, you don't need transaction as select wont do any side effect to your table.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is that you are getting a ***User*** object from the list, and then again adding it to the list. It wont work for the following reasons:

1. You are iterating the list and adding in the same loop which is not allowed and throws **ConcurrentModificationException**.
2. Also you are adding in every iteration. Which means that the list will grow with every iteration and your loop will never end. First you should remove the object and then again add it in the same place.

   #### Solution:

   ```
   public static void execute() {
       getListOfUsers();
       getListOfCustomers();
       for (int i=0;i<listUsers.size();i++) {
           User user = listUsers.remove(i);
           UserTO u = new UserTO();
           Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
           for (Customer customer : listCustomers) {
               if (customer.getCompanyName() == user.getCustomers(customer)) {
                   map.put(customer.getCompanyName(), true);
               } else {
                   map.put(customer.getCompanyName(), false);
               }
           }
           user.getUserId();
           u.setUserId(user.getUserId());
           u.setMap(map);
           listUsers.add(i,user);
       }  
   }
   ```

P.S. - But still I don't get that why there is a need to add an object which already exists in the list without any change.

Comment: I have to do this : list.add(u); I was doing it wrong. Thank you

Comment: Happy to help. And you should upvote the answer if it helps you or mark it as correct if it solves your problem. Anyways... happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting concurrent modification exception as HashMap is not thread safe. Use concurrentHashMap instead. Thanks hope it helps.